# GGTS 3.6.4 can't run project

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, ggts

I'm using GGTS 3.6.4 for Mac.
When I import my project in GGTS which is running without no problems on my other MacBook GGTS shows this error message:

> Loading Grails 2.4.4
>   |Configuring classpath
>   Error |
>   Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>   Error |
>   Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is normally due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy) or missing repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. Please verify your configuration to continue.

The same goes when I try to import the project in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the IDE.

Your application has dependency `xalan:serializer:jar:2.7` which it can't find from your local repositories or from the internet.

This dependency exists in the maven central (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/serializer/2.7.1) which is pretty standard repo to use in any grails app, so make sure your `BuildConfig.groovy` has maven central enabled:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

...

repositories {

    ...
    mavenCentral()
    ...

}

...
```

You mentioned that this app runs on another computer, this is because that computer has locally cached that dependency at some point and grails finds it there. If you remove your local maven cache (`.m2` and/or `.ivy`) you will get the same error on the another computer as well.